# PHP apache2 LAMP After enabling mod php stopped working

Tags: php, apache2, lamp, apache2.4

PHP was working fine before enabling mods. I was trying to use rewrite mods.
I enabled mods with-

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Also restarted apache also restarted computer.
This is my htaccess file-

```
RewriteEngine On

#Accept loading of actual files and folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d

#send everything else to index page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is directory I added to conf-

```
<Directory /var/www/html/folderwithhtaccessfile>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
    </Directory> 
    <Directory /var/www/html/otherfolder>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride None
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
    </Directory>
```

This is my php file-

```
<label>hey hey hey</label>
<?php
echo "bla bla bla";
?>
```

When I run this in browser page Result is -

```
<label>hey hey hey</label>
<?php
echo "bla bla bla";
?>
```

It appears php code is not read by php preprocessor and directly served to browser. Also I have adjuscent folders with php code they have also stopped working not just the one with htaccess file. What might be the problem? Any ideas?

Here is conf-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/folderwithhtaccessfile>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
    </Directory> 
    <Directory /var/www/html/otherfolder>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride None
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**Update**

I partially resolved my problem by enabling php with-

```
a2enmod php8.2
```

Now php is working fine. Javascript is working fine. CSS on the other hand is not working. Files are available and served but no effect can be seen.

Comment: Paste the entire `.conf`

Comment: TEST1: Rename your `.htaccess` file. Does PHP start working again?

Comment: NOTE: You might like to start using Apache 2.4 syntax, the 2.2 syntax you are using is bound to be removed soon  I mean `Order allow,deny    allow from all` which should be `Require all granted` in Apache 2.4 syntax

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Php is not working even if I rename .htaccess. I think I broke something in apache but don't know what is problem.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Conf file is added.

Comment: Javascript, unless you are using node has nothing to do with the server. it all lives in the browser

Comment: ___CSS files are available and served___ How did you check this? Remember we are coming from a place where you said PHP was working fine, but you solved the problem by activating PHP ?!?!?!??!

Comment: I checked if php module is showing. It did not show up in the list so I enabled it which solved issue with PHP. I can see CSS files are loaded in inspect but effect is not there. No issues with Javascript but CSS is not working. Inline CSS is working but CSS files are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `libapache2` seems to be missing:

Try:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php  -y
```

Followed by:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: No it is showing already installed

Comment: What's the `php -v` for your project?

Comment: originally php7.4 now php 8.2. All basic php code so versions should not make any difference.

Comment: Okay so it works for you now. Ideally what I can guess is `libapache2-mod-php  -y` would install the ext for you with the current version php-cli.